# Convert the RoutedEvent to the command for MVVM pattern in WPF

Tags: wpf

How to convert the Checkbox.checked routed event to the command for MVVM pattern?

Reference-Consider the button click routed event, When we assign the command for button then button.click event is considered as command. It executes respective that command.

I googled for it, i got the solution with EventBehaviourFactory. Is it possible without using the EventBehaiourFactory?

Comment: You want to use Command instaad of event or attach command to an event?

Comment: Why can't you bind the Checkbox's IsChecked property TwoWay.

Answer (score 9):

It is a common requirement in WPF. The most widely used solution is using `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801):

Add this xmlns namespace to your xaml:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Then you can do:

```
<CheckBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Of course, you need to add **System.Windows.Interactivity.dll** to your project, located (for me at least) at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\WPF\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`

Comment: Hey thanks. Its really helpful. But if haven't Blend then how to resolve this problem.

Comment: @rohanw: You can download the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) which contains this assembly.

Comment: *"most widely used"* [citation needed]

Comment: Nowadays Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package works for this purpose.