# ConvertBack not fired

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers, ivalueconverter

I'm using my converter like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<Border Name="Border" 
    Background="{Binding
        Path=ConversationState,
        Converter={StaticResource conversationStatusConverter},
        Mode=TwoWay,
        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true,
        ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

This is my triggers definition:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DeepPink" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

And my convert back method:

```cs
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value.ToString() == "DeepPink")
        return ConversationStatus.Active;
    else if (value.ToString() == "Orange")
        return ConversationStatus.UnseenMessage;
    else if (value.ToString() == "LightGray")
        return ConversationStatus.Inactive;
    else return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

When a tab is selected, background goes to deep pink but model is never modified, status stays as before. Source to target works (convert ok), target to source within triggers through isselected property of tab item, doesn't do anything on model.
many thanks !

Comment: How can you say convert (forward) works if status stays as before.   A trigger cascading to a converter - I don't think it was intended to be used that way.  I don't get why you cannot handle the IsSelected of the TabItem.

Answer (score 0):

You simply overwrite the binding, two-way binding only works when the property's *current* value is being changed, e.g. when the user types text into a `TextBox` internally [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) is called for the `Text`-property, leaving any bindings in place.

`Backgrounds` are never changed that way, you cannot change the value in XAML without replacing the binding.

You should try to approach this differently, getting status information from a color seems questionable to say the least anyway. (You won't even get those strings from the brushes, they should convert to something like `#FFFF00FF`)

**Edit:** As noted in the comments you could handle `TabControl.SelectionChanged` and set the status of the newly selected item. And if you really must avoid code-behind in the view (which is *not* required by MVVM!) you could use [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447140/convert-the-routedevent-to-the-command-for-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf) for that as well.

Comment: it's not about the status of the contact, it's just to see if the user read the message by activating the view or not.. I can't get it from anywhere but tabselected. This here is just an example but I really need to make this work. Like gtalk when you have a message the tab will blink, once you activated the tab, it stops blinking.

Comment: @Anna: You could handle the `SelectionChanged` event on the tab control, get the underlying tab data-object and clear its status. As the property is bound the `Background` will then change back automatically.

Comment: It's MVVM... I can't handle it in code behing nor have any UI element in viewmodel. Gonna look into your overwriting binding thing..

Comment: @Anna: Yes you can, it's a myth that you cannot. Also i never said anything about UI-elements in the VM.

Comment: I can have codebehind but no reference to viewmodel ok. But whatever, I can't deal with selectionchanged because tabitem is just a template, and my tabcontrol isbound on observable collection of viewmodels. So I can't get to the tab item, manually change the background property and so on.

Comment: @Anna: I said you should change the property on the VM, not the background, the background is bound and should stay that way. You just need to cast the `SelectedItem` to your VM and change the property.

Comment: ok ! but that'll make my view hold an explicit reference to its viewmodel :/

Comment: @Anna: The view already has a reference to a view-model, at the very least in the DataContext. Besides, views are designed for their view-model, a reference in that direction is fine, the other way around would be troublesome though.